# Lookup using table with separated columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to use `VLOOKUP()` using a table input consisting of columns that are not next to each other.

**Example**

```
MyCell = VLOOKUP(A1, MyTable, 2, FALSE)
MyTable = B1:B10 and D1:D10
```

Is there a way of making this operation work using a *lookup* function or any other worksheet function? Now I get an error.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:
It's because the table is very large and I'm afraid that the operation will slow down the application if I use the entire table as input*

Comment: do you want VBA for that of simply formula?

Comment: I want to find a worksheet function that does the job

Comment: did you test if there is any efficiency problem when you apply your function for that large area of data?? in my opinion there shouldn't be problem to use VLOOKUP for continuous range even it's large one...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
=INDEX(D1:D10,match(A1,B1:B10,0))
```

index/match is typically more efficient than vlookup anyway. if you really want VLOOKUP for just those columns you can use

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,CHOOSE({1,2},B1:B10,D1:D10),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: The choose tip helped me too!Great tip!

Answer (score 2):

In Google Sheets you can use array literals to concatenate two columns:

`= VLOOKUP(A1, {B1:B10,D1:D10}, 2, FALSE)`