# Simple Search Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Sorry for the noob question.

In Excel 2013, I have three columns.

Column A has the data that I would like to search for in Column B.

Column B contains a list of data.

Column C contains the data that states whether the data in Column B is of 'Yes' value or 'No' value.

My question is this: Is there a function or a way in Excel that can search for the data in Column B with the data in Column A as the search criteria?

The data in Column A is already in Column B, I just need to know what the data in Column C is.

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
6712XD  6700XD  Yes
6713XD  6701XD  Yes
6714XD  6702XD  Yes
         ....   Yes
        6712XD  Yes
        6713XD  Yes
        6714XD  Yes
```

Any help is much appreciated, let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: To answer your first question "Yes".  To answer your 2nd question, Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ColA              ColB               ColC
6712XD           6700XD            Yes
6713XD           6701XD            Yes
6714XD           6702XD            Yes

Comment: @howzat Instead of putting data into comments, edit your question so as to include it in the body of the question.  Also look at the links I posted previously so that you add the other helpful information.

Comment: @howzat Please [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120419/326794) your above post and include the sample data there in a structured / usable format.

Comment: I'm still confused after you've posted the data. Are you essentially saying you want that row of Column C to be a VLOOKUP of whether that row of Column A exists in all of Column B?

Comment: @TimEdwards - Yes, although, when I tried the Vlookup option, it didn't work. By the way, none of the columns are in a table, which is why VLOOKUP does not work.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - sorry for the confusion, I have updated the post

Comment: @TimEdwards - The whole of Column A will be in Column B, it's just that Column B is full of data (about 1500 entries) and Column A is only about 20 entries.
The current method I use is to use the Find command (CTRL + F) and search for each piece of data from Column A in Column B

Comment: Still not quite clear on why you've said you can't use VLOOKUP. Are the columns in separate sheets / workbooks etc? Not that that would be a problem either mind you.

Comment: Yes, in seperate workbooks. So I have to copy and paste each cell into this workbook and then do CTRL+F

Comment: @howzat `VLOOKUP` will work on other workbooks.  And it doesn't really matter if the data is in a `TABLE` or merely in a column of cells.  So if that function is not working, you are doing something else to mess it up.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` or `COUNTIF` should all allow you to test for whether value exists. Can you show the formula you have tried to implement?  (You will need to qualify the Workbook/Worksheet names if you're searching from multiple workbooks)

Comment: @DavidZemens - I am using the following formula:       =VLOOKUP(A2,B2:B1349,7,FALSE)

Comment: As you were asked to do with your code, please put the *formula* in your question, and also describe what's *wrong* about the output from this formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula in cell D2:

```
= IF( COUNTIF( B:B, A2 ), C2, "" )
```

`COUNTIF( B:B, A2 )` returns a number of how many times the value of cell A2 is found in column B, 
`C2` is the result value if found, and
`""` is the result value if not found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately this does not work, it returns the answer as FALSE, but when I search the data with CTRL+F, it shows as 'Yes'.

Comment: ... then the value of C2 is actually TRUE and just displayed as Yes. You can try `= IF( COUNTIF( B:B, A2 ), IF( C2, "Yes", "No"), "" )`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from [Lookup using table with separated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403523/lookup-using-table-with-separated-columns), it's:

```
=INDEX(AF:AF,MATCH(P930,Q:Q,0))
```

Thanks for your help :)